# MathText in Matplotlib removing characters

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am attempting to use MathText to bold specific string within my legend. The words are bold but MathText keeps removing specific characters. How can I get MathText to stop removing specific characters? The strings I'm using get appended into a list and used in a legend statement.

For example:

```
nameedit="Bacillus cereus"

#keeps removing the space
r"$\bf{" +nameedit+ r"}$"

#keeps removing the space
r"$\bf" +nameedit+ r"$"

#space removed and %) removed
r"$\bf" +nameedit+' ('+str(round(70/100*100))+'%)'+ r"$"

#does not print anything
r"$\bf{" +nameedit+' ('+str(round(70/100*100))+'%)'+ r"}$"

#Here is the legend statement
ax.legend(circlist,namelegend,bbox_to_anchor=(1,1),loc=2,fontsize=3.3,title='Top Ten Abundance')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string in use is not a valid latex string, it cannot be a valid MathText string.

In order to create a space in latex math mode you can use a backslash - the same works with MathText.

```
r"$\bf{Bacillus\ cereus}$"
```

A `%` sign is a comment in latex. Same with MathText. You need to escape the comment sign to use it as symbol: `\%`

```
r"$\bf{Bacillus\ cereus\ (70\%)}$"
```

[image]

Note however, that you'd get the exact same output by making the text bold altogether, e.g.

```
plt.title("Bacillus cereus (70%)", weight="bold")
```

Comment: Thanks I found online that % was a special character but couldn't find anywhere an escape character. Worked perfectly!